# How to apply a range date filter on angular js year or month?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am new to angular JS. i have a date formatted like that `d MMM y.` however i have two fields one is called from and other to that should filter the `date` as a rang based on year range or month range.
her is how i sort the data.

```
   <div class="transition-item col-md-12" ng-repeat="trn in Transactions">
<div  id="{{'containerOf'+trn.TrnID}}" class="expand-trigger" 
   ng-click="expandTrns('containerOf'+trn.TrnID,'contentOf'+trn.TrnID)">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 transition-desc"><span ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up green-clr': trn.TrnType , 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down red-clr': !trn.TrnType}"></span> {{trn.TrnSubject}}</div>
<div class="col-md-2 transition-amount">{{trn.TrnAmount | currency}}</div>
<div class="col-md-2 transition-date"><small>{{trn.TrnDate | date:"EEE, d MMM y"}}</small></div>
```

her is the form

```
<div class="left form-inline col-md-8">
                 <div class="col-md-5">
                  from :
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="one">
                 </div>

                 <div class="col-md-5">
                   to :
                  <input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="two">
                 </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="sorting">
                <div class="left ">
                Sort :
              </div>
              <div class="btn-toolbar">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#fakelink"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#fakelink"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></a>
                </div>
              </div> <!-- /toolbar -->
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete and I cannot find the `from` and `to` fields you mentioned. Even though you said _here is how i sort the data_ I cannot see any sort logic in the code. Please share what you have tried so that we can help.

Comment: i will edit the post thanks for your replay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still unclear after edit so I'll try to guess that you want to filter a `Date` property of the collection with the input month range. Here's how to do that with [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
<div class="transition-item col-md-12" ng-repeat="trn in Transactions | filter:inMonthRange">
```

`inMonthRange` is the custom filter function defined on scope to check the month of the date.

```
$scope.inMonthRange = function(t){
  return t.dateField.getMonth() + 1 >= $scope.from && t.dateField.getMonth() +1 <= $scope.to;
}
```

You can refer to this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H4Ve7QpJPhQjPsv5GzzB?p=preview) for a working example. Filtering on year is similar.

Comment: thank you i have figured it out the same as you did. but when i call getmonth it is not working her is the format of the date 2015-06-01-T00:00:00

Comment: @user2918388 How did you call it?

Comment: alert(data[1].TrnDate.getMonth());

Comment: Thank you i make it work by  alert(new Date(data[1].TrnDate).getMonth());

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Moment range JS is really useful.

[Click HERE to check it](http://gf3.github.io/moment-range/)